# Force ASUS netbook (without removable battery) to reboot

Tags: reboot, netbook, asus-laptop

I have an ASUS F102B netbook without a removable battery.

It occasionally freezes (or the screen goes flat) and I would like to know a way to force it to restart without waiting for the battery to go flat.

Is there a secret key or button combination that will force a restart on this kind of hardware?

Answer (score 0):

Most, if not all current laptops and netbooks have a 2 stage power button.  Tapping it quickly will turn it on or initiate a shutdown (if it is set that way in the OS.) 
The second stage is to force the unit off by holding the power button down for typically 5 seconds (I tell folks to do a slow count to 6, which usually works.)

Comment: This works, but it's not as good as shutting down the netbook with the keyboard if there is a way to shut down the ASUS F102B with the keyboard using a secret key or button combination.

Comment: If the OS is hung, there isn't much other option.  If the OS is still functioning you can set the power button and sleep button to shutdown and see if that works the way you want it to.

Comment: If the OS is hung on my laptop, there is a keyboard combination to safely restart it that is software defined by the operating system, not hardware defined by the laptop. There is also a software defined keyboard combination to kill the user session which brings it back to the initial login screen.

Comment: @MarkCraypo Thanks for your answer here. A family member has taken the machine away on vocation and it will be two weeks before I can corroborate this.